# Enable copy/paste on html5 date field

Tags: javascript, html

Am able to copy values from textbox and paste into another textbox in my html5 form. Same way how can i copy value from the date field.

`<input type="date" />`

I want to copy value from one date field and paste it to another date field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**By native?**

No, a date `input` field behaves differently than a text `input` field.

**Workaround**

I had the same problem once and created a workaround.

When you `dlbclick` the input field, it temporarily changes itself to a `text` input field and automatically select its value. So you can copy the date by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

It also works when you want to copy a date from and text field into the date input field.

Register a `focusout` event to reset the input to its original state `type="date"`.

```js
// get all date input fields
let dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="date"]');

dateInputs.forEach(el => {
    // register double click event to change date input to text input and select the value
    el.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
        el.type = "text";
        
        // After changing input type with JS .select() wont work as usual
        // Needs timeout fn() to make it work
        setTimeout(() => {
          el.select();
        })
    });
    
    // register the focusout event to reset the input back to a date input field
    el.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
        el.type = "date";
    });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<label>Double click me</label>
<input type="date" value="2011-09-29" />
<input type="date" placeholder="paste the date here" />
```

Comment: I want to paste in another `date` component

Comment: See updated anwser. Copy and paste the first date in the seconds date field.

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding! ;)

Comment: Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

So, you can do this with **jQuery** using the `copy` and `paste` events to take the value from one and insert it in to another **using a fake clipboard**.

#### Update

**Note**: I've just found a weird quirk with this. If you click on the first date box and type a date, you then need to click OFF the input before copying. The same goes for pasting in to the second box. I can't figure out why this is.

```js
var dateClipboard;

$("input[type='date']").on("copy", function(){
 dateClipboard = $(this).val();
 alert("copied");
})

$("input[type='date']").on("paste", function(){
 if(dateClipboard != ''){
   $(this).val(dateClipboard); 
   alert("pasted");
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="test" id="test">
<input type="date" name="test" id="test2">
```

Comment: Is that possible to make it in Javascript.? Because am working in ReactJS application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using jQuery)

```
$(() => {
    $(document).on("keydown", "input[type=date]", function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey === true) {
            if (e.keyCode === 67) {
                $(this).attr("type", "text").select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                $(this).attr("type", "date");
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).bind("paste", function (e) {
        let $input = $(document.activeElement);
        if ($input.attr("type") === "date") {
            $input.val(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to Red's answer, allowing date, datetime and datetime-local. A small change that I hope will help someone.

```js
// get all date input fields
let dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="datetime-local"], [type="datetime"], [type="date"]');
dateInputs.forEach(el => {
    var type = el.type;
    // register double click event to change date input to text input and select the value
    el.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
        el.type = "text";
        
        // After changing input type with JS .select() wont work as usual
        // Needs timeout fn() to make it work
        setTimeout(() => {
          el.select();
        })
    });
    
    // register the focusout event to reset the input back to a date input field
    el.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
        el.type = type;
    });
});
```

```html
<br><label>Double click me</label>
<input type="date" value="2022-03-10" />
<input type="date" placeholder="paste the date here" />

<br><br><br><br>

<br><label>Double click me</label>
<input type="datetime-local" value="2022-03-10T09:50" />
<input type="datetime-local" placeholder="paste the date here" />
```

Comment: I know this is kind of a "meta question", but why do HTML5 date fields lack full-field copy-and-paste (in at least 2 browsers, Chrome & Edge)? That seems a no-brainer need for people who do actual work. Maybe I'm not understanding something about the standards committee's philosophy? If so, I'd like to be educated on their reason. It may explain other browser "oddities" also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I merged Lewis and phoenix-gi to make a code that works for JS

```js
let dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="date"]');
var dateClipboard;

dateInputs.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('copy', () => {
        dateClipboard = el.value;
        //alert("copied");
    });

    el.addEventListener('paste', () => {
        if(dateClipboard != ''){
           el.value  = dateClipboard; 
           //alert("pasted");
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="test" id="test">
<input type="date" name="test" id="test2">
```