# Strage behaviour with jQuery Events and Date fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, input

## Context

I was trying to answer the question [Enable copy/paste on html5 date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981660/enable-copy-paste-on-html5-date-field/49982055#49982055) which asks how to copy and paste from one `<input type='date'>` field to another.

## The Problem

While I came up with something that works, I ran in to a weird quirk. You have to first select the date box and then *deselect* (click anywhere else) it before the `copy` event will fire. The same goes for the `paste` event.

The steps to reproduce the problem are;

1. Select the first date input
2. Type a date
3. Deselect the date input (click anywhere)
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
5. Select the second date field
6. Deselect it (click anywhere)
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

## What I've tried

Along with the code in the snippet below, I've tried using the `bind` method, the `on` method and the `delegate` method and have had the same problem with all of them.

Does anyone know why this is? Is it something to do with Focus?

## Update #1

I'm using Chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit).

```js
var dateClipboard;

$("input[type='date']").on("copy", function(){
 dateClipboard = $(this).val();
 alert("copied");
})

$("input[type='date']").on("paste", function(){
 if(dateClipboard != ''){
 $(this).val(dateClipboard); 
  alert("pasted");
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" name="test" id="test">
<input type="date" name="test" id="test2">
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm using Chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) - I can only copy/paste when I've clicked on the first date, typed a date, deselected the input, press ctrl+c